# Options for multiple comparisons in vegan::simper

Tags: r, vegan

I am using the `adonis` function in the `vegan` package to determine differences in dissimilarities in a community (PCB congeners) between several different factors. I also have decided to use the `simper` function to assess which community members contributed most to the observed differences. Is there a way for to include multiple factors in the `simper` function? I ran the `adonis` model shown below successfully, but the corresponding code for the `simper` function doesn't work. Many thanks.

```
# Adonis model
pcbtest3 <- adonis(pcbcong ~ FISH_CLASS+REACH+BASIN,
                   data=pcbcov,
                   method="bray",
                   permutations=999
                   )
# pcbcong=matrix of community dissimilarities
# FISH_CLASS,REACH, BASIN are factors
# Simper
simp <- with(pcbcov, simper(pcbcong,(FISH_CLASS, BASIN, REACH)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`simper` can be used only with one grouping variable.

A workaround would be to use `interaction()` to create a new grouping variable from all three factors.

Interpretation of this will be  awkward (depending how many factor levels you have) and I don't know if that`s meaningful at all - so be careful.

Comment: For my factors: FISH_CLASS has two levels, REACH has two levels, and BASIN has 3 levels.  Would it be inappropriate to create a new factor that groups all factors together and rerun simper?

Comment: Why not use an ordination technique? (maybe dbRDA? oder tbRDA?)

Comment: Isn't redundancy analysis somewhat equivalent to regression?  My question is that I have a nested design where I want to compare the factors FISH_CLASS and REACH nested within BASIN. Thoughts?

Comment: This platform is for programming related questions. For general statistical questions, please ask on CrossValidated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/